# Prove that $\sum_{k=1}^{+\infty}a_k=\sum_{k=1}^{+\infty}\int_0^1\frac{\sin(kx)}{k^x}dx$ is divergent.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I am struggling with the following series:

$$
\sum_{k=1}^{+\infty}a_k=\sum_{k=1}^{+\infty}\int_0^1\frac{\sin(kx)}{k^x}dx.
$$

The general term $a_k$ is clearly well defined for every $k\geq1$ since $\int_0^1\frac{\sin(kx)}{k^x}dx$ is well defined for every $k\geq1$. I should prove that this series is divergent.

As a second request, I should prove that hence the series of functions
$$
\sum_{k=1}^{+\infty}\frac{\sin(kx)}{k^x}
$$
does not converge uniformly. This, given the first request, is quite clear since if this series of functions was uniformly convergent, then we could write

$$
\sum_{k=1}^{+\infty}\int_0^1\frac{\sin(kx)}{k^x}dx=\int_0^1\sum_{k=1}^{+\infty}\frac{\sin(kx)}{k^x}dx=\int_0^1 S(x)dx<+\infty
$$
since $S(x)$ is continuous on $[0,1]$, being the uniform limit of a series of continuous functions on $[0,1]$.
How could I proceed with the first request?

Comment: Haven't been able to solve it, but just sharing some thoughts in case you or others would be interested. Since $x\in (0,1)$, $k^x < k$ which means $$\sum_{k\ge 1} a_k \ge \sum_{k\ge 1} \int_0^1 \frac{\sin kx}{k} = \sum_{k\ge 1} \frac{1-\cos k}{k^2}$$

Comment: @epsilon-emperor: No, $k^x<k$ doesn't imply the last inequality ($\sin kx$ isn't always nonnegative).

Comment: Oops, good catch! I overlooked that! @metamorphy

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Integrating twice by parts gives
\begin{align*}
\int_0^1 {\frac{{\sin (kx)}}{{k^x }}dx} & = \frac{1}{k} - \frac{{\cos (k)}}{{k^2 }} - \frac{{\log k}}{k}\int_0^1 {\frac{{\cos (kx)}}{{k^x }}dx} 
\\ & = \frac{1}{k} - \frac{{\cos (k)}}{{k^2 }} - \frac{{\sin (k)\log k}}{{k^3 }} - \frac{{\log ^2 k}}{{k^2 }}\int_0^1 {\frac{{\sin (kx)}}{{k^x }}dx} ,
\end{align*}
i.e.,
$$
\int_0^1 {\frac{{\sin (kx)}}{{k^x }}dx}  = \left( {\frac{1}{k} - \frac{{\cos (k)}}{{k^2 }} - \frac{{\sin (k)\log k}}{{k^3 }}} \right)\frac{{k^2 }}{{k^2  + \log ^2 k}}.
$$
Consequently,
$$
\int_0^1 {\frac{{\sin (kx)}}{{k^x }}dx}  \sim \frac{1}{k}
$$
for large $k$. The divergence follows from the limit comparison test.